# Ubuntu One music store 20gb Promotion

Tags: ubuntu-one

Just wondering about the Ubuntu One promotion where you get 20GB and 6 months streaming for buying a song. Does that 20GB apply to anything or just music, and does it last forever or just for 6 months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It applies to anything, increasing your total storage space to 25GB, and only lasts for the 6 months of the promotion.